# Change the animation from pushViewController to vertical

Tags: objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, push

I have 2 collectionViewController, each filled with cells with images where I can scroll through horizontally. Both are nested on a navigationViewController.

Now, if I push a button, one controller shall switch to another with push:

```
[myNavController pushViewController:collectionViewController1 animated:YES];
```

How can I change the animation so the collectionViewController doesn't appear from the side, so that it comes in from the top/bottom?

Thanks for the help!

Edit:
I solved the problem another way:
I nested the 2 CollectionViewController inside a ScrollView.The Scrollview has the height of two screens. Now I can swipe from one to another CollectionView with no huzzle :). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to push onto the navigation stack, then you need to implement your own custom animations for this. However if you want it to just display on top of the current viewController you can use the modal presentation for this.

**Edit:**

Here is a tutorial that should get you started.

http://www.appcoda.com/custom-view-controller-transitions-tutorial/

Comment: Do you have an example for a custom animation for the pushViewController method? Is there a delegate I can override? I am not that into animations still.

Comment: I've added a tutorial that should point you in the right direction. There is a fair amount of work that goes into it. But worth the effort if pulled off correctly! Good luck!